# iOS 6 OpenGL ES 2.0 video memory leak in a render buffer object

Tags: ios, ios6, opengl-es

Below is an example code that behaves like one leaking a video memory on iPad 2 IOS 6.1 (basically it creates a render buffer object, allocates a memory for it and destroys it after drawing):

if I put it into a draw loop I see lots of memory warnings and finally the application is killed by OS. Instruments give no hints and I even cannot see any memory size growth, only memory warnings.

I understand that creating buffers in a draw loop is a bad idea, but the buffer needs to be recreated anyway in case if user rotates a device and resolution changes so the leak will remain but need more time to kill the app (also looks like springboard restarts sometimes when the application is killed).

So the example below is just a way to reproduce a problem that is usually hidden, I think.
I would be glad to here any ideas on what's wrong here and how this leak can be fixed.

There are several things I tried (see commented code) but nothing really helped. The only thing that helps is commenting of a glClear and glDrawArrays calls.

Looks like GPU doesn't touch the render buffer in this case and the problem disappears, but I need to clear that buffer and draw something to it (the reason why I need that buffer is next:

I try to implement a multi-sampled rendering into a texture, which works in fact, but leaks memory).
I check for glGetError() after every GL call and no errors appear.

```
GLuint rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
//glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA4, 2000 , 2000);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, 2000 , 2000);

/*GLuint fbo_faa;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_faa);*/
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer/*fbo_faa*/);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
```

Comment: I pasted your code into one of my existing project's main draw method. I tried binding it to my main frame buffer and tried to create a separate one. I can not get any memory leak or any other kind of problems at all. Is it possible some other code is responsible for that?

Comment: @peter, Sorry for late reply. If I put the code into standard GLES2Sample ES2Renderer - (void)render method before the [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER] call it behaves like described above. Did you run it on device or on simulator?

Comment: Here is my output (as you can see from time stamps, the first warning appears right after the launch, while you need to wait a bit for the second one to appear)...

Comment: 2013-05-17 10:13:34.022 GLES2Sample[2044:907] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2013-05-17 10:13:35.045 GLES2Sample[2044:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 10:14:00.810 GLES2Sample[2044:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 10:14:04.026 GLES2Sample[2044:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 10:14:04.203 GLES2Sample[2044:907] Received memory warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now what you are doing and I have no idea why your code works in one of my projects. Anyway, it would seem you keep attaching render buffers to your frame buffer. The best guess would be they are not deleted as you did not signal the GL that those render buffers are no longer in use. So you do need to discard attachments and reattach the main render buffer.. Try pasting this code and tell me how it turns out..

```
    GLuint rbo;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    //glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA4, 2000 , 2000);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, 2000 , 2000);

    /*GLuint fbo_faa;
     glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_faa);*/
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer/*fbo_faa*/);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    const GLenum discards[]  = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 1, discards);

    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
```

Comment: OK, that works with no problems. Now I'm convinced that there would be no leaks if I recreate a buffer only when the resolution changes. But a question remains: why it doesn't leak only if you do both discard and attach an another render buffer. If I discard and detach all the render buffers, for example, it still leaks... Any ideas about that? A bug in driver? Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way, If I attach another render buffer but don't discard I still see two or three memory warnings that stop appearing then :) So the application works and is never killed, the only problem is those several warnings. This becomes more and more interesting :)

Comment: Anyway, creating buffers on every draw is a really bad idea :)

Comment: @peter, I forgot to enter your name in my comments. Thank you again.

Comment: Several minutes of work without discard gave nexe output (application still running)... 2013-05-17 13:21:46.575 GLES2Sample[279:907] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2013-05-17 13:21:47.947 GLES2Sample[279:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 13:21:52.697 GLES2Sample[279:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 13:21:52.893 GLES2Sample[279:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 13:23:01.032 GLES2Sample[279:907] Received memory warning.
2013-05-17 13:28:56.466 GLES2Sample[279:907] Received memory warning.

Comment: First of all I have no idea who Peter is :) As for creating buffers on each draw call does seem a bit too much, though it should work never the less. Still you must consider that openGL works kind of like massaging system with the GPU, you do not have much control over it. You make a request to delete the buffer but cant predict when and if it will really be deleted. You might also need to call some glFlush or even glFinish to force all the commands to be executed on the fly. The glFinish might even block your thread until the commands are completed.